# How to get all associated information for images in media library that would be returned by REST endpoint

Tags: wordpress, rest

My original problem is that the WordPress REST endpoint that I am using has a built in "posts_per_page" maximum of 100.  I have not been successful in changing the built in endpoint, so I am trying to create my own endpoint.  I have successfully created the endpoint, but I can't figure out how to get all of the same information that the built in endpoint gets.

The built in endpoint is at [/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=.svg&per_page=100](http:///wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=.svg&per_page=100).
The custom endpoint is at https://amaxalaus.bigriverwebdesign.com/wp-json/amaxalaus/v1/svgs.
The important information that is not in the custom endpoint includes: "source_url", Advanced Custom Fields, media categories (created by a plugin).

Here is my code to create the custom endpoint.

```
function get_svgs() { //defining a function to get all SVGs from media library
    $images = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ) 
    );
    return($images);
}    

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {  //rest endpoint to get more than 100 SVGs

            register_rest_route( 'amaxalaus/v1', 'svgs',array(

                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_svgs'

            ) );

} );
```

If anyone knows how to modify the existing endpoint to return more than 100 per page, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your function.php theme file or creating a plugin will bump your number too 200 (or whatever number you set). It's from [here](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2914#issuecomment-266222585).

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_collection_params', 'my_prefix_change_post_per_page', 10, 1 );

function my_prefix_change_post_per_page( $params ) {
    if ( isset( $params['per_page'] ) ) {
        $params['per_page']['maximum'] = 200;
    }

    return $params;
}
```